# VBA error 1004 Sorry, we couldn't find

Tags: vba, path, find

I've receive the above error for the following code:

```
            Dim location_results As String
            location_results = Worksheets("merging").Range("B1").Text 'absorbing the initial computation results folder
            file_results = Dir$(location_results & "\" & "*" & NBDID & "*" & ".*") 'checks if there is a file with NBDID in the "location results folder
            If (Len(file_results) > 0) Then
                Worksheets("list").Range("D" & i).Value = file_results                         
            Else
                MsgBox (NBDID & " result not found")
            End If

            'problem todoB:
lineD:
            Dim shortlocation As String
            shortlocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\megaresults\" & file_results
On Error GoTo lineD
                'Workbooks(shortlocation).Open
                Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=shortlocation)
                'Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(location_results & file_results)
                Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(location_merger & file_merger)
                On Error GoTo 0
```

The error is raised on the line:

```
                Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(location_results & file_results)
```

and on the line:

```
                Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=shortlocation)
```

Now googling that error, nearly everyone has an issue that the file they are trying to open is not in the parents-workbook folder, or that they did not preappend their path to the file specification.

I have done that however, and the path is validated, both manually by me checking whether the file is in the folder, as well as with:

```
            If (Len(file_results) > 0) Then
                Worksheets("list").Range("D" & i).Value = file_results                         
            Else
                MsgBox (NBDID & " result not found")
            End If
```

, the file exists, and the total path, including file name and extention is 222 characters long. It also contains spaces.

But I can't find any reason for it to return as an error. On top of that, the on error goto lineD does not function, it still pops up with a message that does not allow continuing of the code.

Could someone point out my mistake to me, or give me a solution that would work?

Kind regards.

Comment: Which line is the error raised for?

Comment: Where exactly are you validating the path? I don't see any validation code for either `shortlocation` or `location_merger & file_merger` actually existing.

Comment: @Comintern I've incorporated the answers to your questions in the initial question, I believe that's the way I'm supposed to work here on this forum.